# Placing an apple in snake game written in Scala

Tags: scala

To place an apple in an empty place, I'm using the *emptySpots()* method to locate the points of the cells that are empty or free.

When I implement the code below, my game runs fine:

```
    def emptySpots() : Point = {
        val emptyPointsList = new ArrayBuffer[Point]()
        var emptyLocation : Point = new Point(0,0)
        
        emptyLocation = Point(random.randomInt(upTo = 25), random.randomInt(upTo = 25))
        emptyLocation
      }
```

However, when I try to implement the code below, it shows me errors:

```
    def emptySpots() : Point = {
        val emptyPointsList = new ArrayBuffer[Point]()
        var emptyLocation : Point = new Point(0,0)

        for(i <- 0 until gridDims.height) {
          for(j <- 0 until gridDims.width) {
            if(getCellType(Point(i, j)) == Empty()) {
              emptyPointsList += Point(i, j)
            }
          }
        }
        if(!emptyPointsList.isEmpty) {
          emptyLocation = emptyPointsList(random.randomInt(emptyPointsList.size))
        }
        emptyLocation
      }
```

The errors are:
[image]

I would appreciate if anyone could point out what's wrong in my second implementation to show me such errors where my first implementation works fine.

P.S. The randomInt() is not wrong here because it's supported by the imported package and library

Comment: What package did you import for the random generator? Just because the method exists doesn't mean it is producing the correct result. Assign the `random.randomInt(...)` to a value, put a break point there and see what it produces

Comment: **import engine.random.{RandomGenerator, ScalaRandomGen}** is what I used and this method runs fine for me when I'm double checking separately. Also this is my assignment. This method randomInt() is working fine for the others as well

Comment: There is a logic issue in your code. You are checking if your buffer is empty and then trying to extract an element from an empty buffer. You either need to change it to `if(!emptyPointsList.isEmpty)` or figure out what the correct semantics of your code is supposed to be

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the mistake but unfortunately, it's not working again. Some of my friends just reviewed my code and they are also confused.

Comment: Post the full stack trace and make sure the code is actually being run and the error doesn't come from JVM startup. There are methods in this code that we don't know what they do. It isn't possible for us to help without knowing exactly what line is throwing the error